# How to keep line breaks after mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php

I'm working on a simple messaging web. The process is simple, I enter the text with line breaks and it will be saved on the database and display it in another div. Everything was fine until I used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which removed all the line breaks and display whole text in a single line

```
$text = $_POST['new_text'];

$vaild_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($text));
$vaild_text = strip_tags($vaild_text);  

$breaked_text = nl2br($vaild_text);   

$command = "INSERT INTO textTable (text_col)VALUES ('$breaked_text')";    
$query = mysqli_query($con,$command);
```

If I remove `mysqli_real_escape_string()` everything 
works very well but for the matter of security I Can't

I even changed the `nl2br()` position and put it after and before `mysqli_real_escape_string()`
     but it didn't work!

Comment: Use prepared statements and you won't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: What error are you getting if any? And what do you see as the result in mysql

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
// Strip the tags and convert the newlines to line breaks
$text = strip_tags($_POST['new_text']);   
$breaked_text = nl2br($text);

// Prepare the query
$statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO textTable (text_col) VALUES (?);");
$statement->bind_param("s", $breaked_text); // The "s" stands for Strings

// Execute the SQL query
$statement->execute();
```

Using *Prepared Statements* has a few benefits:

1. It prevents SQL injections by escaping the parameters.
2. It's faster if you want to execute the query multiple times, because the query is *prepared* only once.
3. No need to concatenate the values into the query. Of course, the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function could be an alternative for concatenating a string when not using prepared statements. I *do* recommend prepared statements though.

You can find more benefits and examples about *Prepared Statements* in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5662391/3625118

More information about the `bind_param()` function can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution all I need to use id nl2br() for displaying the text

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quert);
$text = $data['text_col'];
$text_break_line = nl2br($text);
echo "<p>'$text_break_line'</p>";
```

Comment: I'd still recommend using _Prepared Statements_ for safety purposes (and because it's easier to manage)