# All-around protection of users meddling with inputs

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Im new here. I already know that this question will be rather unspecific but I cant seem to find a good result googling. If it turns out that this question has been asked before please just link me to it.

I have a searchfunction and Im trying to secure it from any meddling (SQL Injections/XXS, etc.).

My searchfunction does the following:

Upon pressing the "search" button it removes quotes and apostrophs:

```
$(document).on('click', '#event-search-button', function(event){

    search     = ($(".search-events").val()).replace(/([\"\'])/g,'\\'); 
    from_date  = $("#date-from").val().replace(/([\"\'])/g,'\\');
    to_date    = $("#date-to").val().replace(/([\"\'])/g,'\\');
    event_type = $("#typfilter").val().replace(/([\"\'])/g,'\\');
```

Then I send the data to a php file with AJAX and in said file I wrap `htmlspecialchars()` around the variables:

```
$search    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']); 
$from_date = htmlspecialchars($_POST['from_date']);
$to_date = htmlspecialchars($_POST['to_date']);
$event_type = htmlspecialchars($_POST['event_type']);
```

Now  I assume Im safe from most meddling but turns out that theres atleast 1 (probably more) thing that the user can still do to mess with my SQL.

If the user types in % he will get a listing of all results. While pretty harmless its still annoying.

Is there a plugin or something else that acts as an "all-arounder" for such cases and removes all chars that could be damaging? I am aware of PDO but I am way to deep into this project to re-vamp all of my Queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PDO, but if you want to protect your SQL queries from injection you'll need to use prepared statements and bound parameters.

Have a look at these links:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
[Advantages of using prepared statements over normal mysqli statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662346/advantages-of-using-prepared-statements-over-normal-mysqli-statements)